# de un campo varchar,sacar mes ,año y día

Tags: sql-server

tengo una duda resulta que tengo un campo de tipo varchar que es la fecha necesito separar esta fecha en dia mes y año  alguien podría ayudarme

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Por qué no declaraste ese campo del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`? Ahora tienes este problema y tendrás más cuando necesites hacer cálculos con fechas, o posibilidad a datos erróneos como `2019-20-50`  a veces los usuarios están despistados y escriben cosas así y las insertan en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Y en que formato tienes la fecha?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las funciones YEAR, MONTH Y DAY sobre el campo que deseas.

[image: Consulta sql]

Saludos

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS,otra pregunta con ello me cambia toda la columna o solo un campo

Comment: Si quieres unirlos esos 3 campos en uno solo puedes usar la funcion CONCAT, en la cuál lo que desees concatenar va separado por comas. Por ejemplo: SELECT CONCAT(DAY('2019-03-26'), '/', MONTH('2019-03-26'), '/', YEAR('2019-03-26')) FECHA        ....... eso te mostrará un solo campo con el alias que le puse FECHA.